# I lose audio sometimes when I close the Systems Sound dialog box in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, sound, 22.04, pulseaudio

I have a Jabra evolve2 85 which loses sound somewhat randomly.  I'll switch from one youtube channel to another, for example, and the sound will cut out.  Sometimes, if I open the Ubuntu System app and select the sound tab, the audio will reappear. Throughout this, the sound sink is always the Jabra Link 380.  It just mutes if I terminate the box and reappears when the System/Sound dialog is open.   I'm using Pulseaudio.  Same thing, btw, with the pulseaudio volume control app.  When I lose audio, opening up the app restores sound. Closing the app loses sound.
I thought that it might be Jabra's firmware on the headset, which (IMHO) is a horror show.  The specific thing I hate is that there's a muting feature that mutes sound when you switch  sound sources or even when another sound source requests access.  So you are sitting in a google meeting and a phone call comes in and **your sound is muted whether or not you want to answer the phone.**  Jabra assumes that the person calling is more important that your meetiong.  It's insanely poor logic.  But for now, I'd settle for knowing how to ensure that my sound remains connected to the computer, and that it functions.
My video card is an nvidia and I have the latest driver for that sound card.  Not sure if its relevant...